# CoreWLAN CWEventDelegate EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the event function gets called

Tags: swift, macos, corewlan

So I'm using CoreWLAN, and I needed to register some events; I got started by trying one event, `CWEventType.ssidDidChange`. Then I have the appropriate function according to Apple Docs to handle it `func ssidDidChangeForWiFiInterface(withName interfaceName: String)`. But when the event fires (I reset my wifi to simulate an SSID change), I get an error like this `Thread 2: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

Apple documentation pages I was using:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan/cwwificlient/1512439-startmonitoringevent
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan/cweventtype
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan/cweventdelegate
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan/cweventdelegate/1512422-ssiddidchangeforwifiinterface

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreWLAN
import Cocoa

class WLANMonitor: CWEventDelegate {
    var client: CWWiFiClient = CWWiFiClient.shared();
    init() {
        self.client.delegate = self
    }

    func registerEvents() {
        puts("Registering for SSID change...")
        do {
            try client.startMonitoringEvent(with: CWEventType.ssidDidChange);
        } catch {
            print("Error");
        }
    }

    func ssidDidChangeForWiFiInterface(withName interfaceName: String) 
    {
        print("Changed SSID")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should set up an exception breakpoint in Xcode and see what is the actual exception thrown and on which line does that occur. Btw you shouldn't use `;` in Swift.

Comment: I set up some breakpoints, but the ones on the event never actually show when running. I'm not 100% sure how to catch the actual exception.

Comment: Check [Exception breakpoint in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)

Comment: I still get the same error in the same place.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AnWr2CI